# Writing a fixed-width text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing an app that creates a fixed-width text file. What I've already written works just fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method. (By efficient, I mean executes faster, not uses less code.)

Here is the function I've created that pads or trims strings to the required length:

```
Private Function ToLen(ByRef strLen As String, ByRef intLen As Integer) As String

    Dim L As Integer = Len(strLen)
    If L < intLen Then
        Return strLen & Strings.Space(intLen - L)
    ElseIf L = intLen Then
        Return strLen
    Else
        Return Strings.Left(strLen, intLen)
    End If

End Function
```

Here is a simplified version of the code that calls it:

```
Using MyFile1 As New StreamWriter("C:\Temp\MyFile.txt")
    Do
        ' loop through records
        MyFile1.WriteLine(ToLen(Item1, 10) & ToLen(Item2, 50) & ToLen(Item3, 25))
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: you might want to try code review for this question.[CodeReview Site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would measure the performance against string.Format with some fixed size fields. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86413/creating-a-fixed-width-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I hadn't heard of CodeReview yet, nor was I aware that Format had that kind of flexibility.

Comment: You can't fix the perf of a file writing program.  The slow part is writing the file, it is orders of magnitude slower than the processor and your code.  You'll need to buy more RAM to make it faster.  An SSD doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I'm aware of that and I appreciate the points you make, but the concept may be applicable to other situations as well. I'm just looking for coding efficiencies here.

Comment: @kenny - The String.Format method appears to be several times slower than the code I was already using. Apparently Format's flexibility comes with a steep price. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the new .NET methods for string manipulation rather than the old-style VB6 functions, for instance:

```
Private Function ToLen(text As String, length As Integer)
    If text.Length > length Then
        Return text.SubString(0, length)
    Else
        Return text.PadRight(length)
    End If
End Function
```

Then, when you are writing to the file, don't concatenate the strings together.  It would be more efficient to call `Write` multiple times:

```
Using MyFile1 As New StreamWriter("C:\Temp\MyFile.txt")
    Do
        ' loop through records
        MyFile1.Write(ToLen(Item1, 10))
        MyFile1.Write(ToLen(Item2, 50))
        MyFile1.WriteLine(ToLen(Item3, 25))
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Although the difference is only a few percent, the SubString and PadRight methods do increase speed a little for strings that are longer or shorter. For strings already of the desired length though, the PadRight method adds significant processing, so I added "ElseIf text.Length = length Then ... Return strLen" into your ToLen function. Good point about the .NET vs VB6-style string handling by the way. Thanks Steven!

Comment: @Caben Glad to help.  I wondered if checking if the lengths were the same would make a difference.  According to the MSDN, `PadRight` returned the original string if they were the same, but apparently not as efficiently :)  I thought of using `String.Format` too but I figured if speed was the goal, that wouldn't be as efficient since it would have to parse the format string and everything.